# How to calculate bootstrap adjusted odds ratios from logistic regression analysis in SAS?

Tags: sas, logistic-regression, statistics-bootstrap

Using the following code, I performed multivariable logistic regression analysis, and adjusted odds ratios for each variable were calculated.

| category1 | cagtegory2 | continuous1 | continuous2 | result |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | b | 11 | 19 | 0 |
| b | b | 13 | 14 | 1 |
| c | a | 15 | 12 | 0 |
| c | a | 13 | 11 | 1 |
| a | b | 14 | 16 | 0 |
| b | c | 13 | 14 | 1 |

```
proc logistic 
   plots(only)=all;
   class category1 category2
   model result= continuous1 continuous2 category1 category2
   selection=none
   link=logit
run;
```

In this code, independent variables are two continuous variables (continuous1 and 2) and two categorical variable (category1 and 2). A dependent variable is 'result'.

**Question>** Using these variables, I  want to calculate additionally adjusted odds ratios and their 95% confidence interval by bootstrap method (on 1000 bootstrapped samples). They can be easily calculated in SPSS using bootstrap option. However, I cannot find such a option in SAS.

If the coding for this analysis is complex, where can I find such information? Thank you very much in advance!!

Comment: Check out the `%boot` and `%bootci` macros. https://blogs.sas.com/content/iml/2018/07/23/boot-and-bootci-macros-sas.html. There is also a more detailed article on doing bootstrap analysis in SAS by Rick Wicklin: https://blogs.sas.com/content/iml/2018/12/12/essential-guide-bootstrapping-sas.html

Comment: Use the blog method, not the macros - they're a bit outdated. The blog method is pretty straightforward with the BY functionality. Note that PROC SURVEYLOGISTIC will do bootstrap variance estimates but not odds ratio as far as I know.

Comment: Thank you for your replies. I will try to solve this problem with the method in the blog. Thank you~!